# error al realizar acciones segun argumentos de entrada (argparse)

Tags: python, argparse

Estoy utilizando argparse para ejecutar mi programa sin tener que inicializarlo y pasandole los valores desde antes. tengo una lista de favoritos y quisiera que cuando se le pase el argumento -f al script se muestre en pantalla la lista de favoritos por lo que hice lo siguiente:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import argparse

favoritos = ['a','e','i','o','u']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args == '-f':
    print(favoritos)
```

pero a la hora de utilizarlo me sale lo siguiente:

```
./example.py -f

usage: example.py [-h] [-f F]
example.py: error: argument -f: expected one argument
```

Quisiera saber como hacer para que al pasar el argumento `-f` (sin nada mas) se mostrara la lista de favoritos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes recibir un argumento que si se agrega vale True, de lo contrario False. Esto lo podemos lograr con `action='store_true'`

Luego, podemos obtener el valor del argumento (que será True o False dependiendo que se haya pasado) usando `args.f`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

if(args.f):
    print("aqui va tu código")
```

Esta información la saqué de [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) de add_argument.